# html element doesn't move correctly with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, position

I have to repair bottom slider on http://rhemapress.pl/www_wopr/ . If you see when you click right arrow twice, then animation back to start and animate again. Here when i click one on right arrow time this should be blocked and not possible to click second time.

Numer of moves right is created dynamicly by checkWidth();

```
    function checkWidth() {

        var elements = $('.items').children().length;

        var width = Math.ceil(elements / 5) * 820;

        return width;
    }
```

This return realWidth witch is something like limit of offset. Variable offset is setted to 0 at start. So, if i click right, then in method moveRight() is checked if element can be moved and it's move. At end offset is increment by 820px (one page of slider), so if we've got 2 pages, then next move can't be called. But it is and this is problem! :/

My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.prev').bind('click',moveLeft);
    $('a.next').bind('click',moveRight);


    var realWidth = checkWidth(); 
    realWidth -= 820;

    var offset = 0;


    function moveLeft(e) {

        var position = $('.items').position();
        var elements = $('.items').children().length;

        if ((elements > 5) && ((offset - 820) >= 0) ) {
            $('.items').animate({
            'left': (position.left + 820)
            }, 300, function() {
                offset -= 820;
            });

        }
    }

    function moveRight(e) {

        var position = $('.items').position();
        var elements = $('.items').children().length;

        if ((elements > 5) && ((offset + 820) <= realWidth)) {        

            $('.items').animate({
            'left': (position.left - 820)
            }, 300, function() {
                offset += 820;
            });
        }
    }

    function checkWidth() {

        var elements = $('.items').children().length;

        var width = Math.ceil(elements / 5) * 820;

        return width;
    }
});
</script>
```

How can i do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to prevent the click event from firing before the current animation is complete.  You can do this by preventing the rest of the function from executing if the element is currently being animated:

```
function moveLeft(e) {
   if ($(this).is(":animated")) {
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for this but bug is still here. I want to prevent before call animation again when `offset == realWidth`. When `offset == realWidth` i can call `moveRight()` again - i must block it. When offset has max value (`= realWidth`) then any click on right arrow can't move object - only left arrow can move.

Comment: @TomaszSzulc you can add that condition to your function: `function moveRight(e) { if (offset == realWidth) { return false; ...`

Comment: look at this - http://pastebin.com/QhsPiUUA it doesn't stop. check it on http://rhemapress.pl/www_wopr/ :/

Comment: @TomaszSzulc what are the actual values of `offset` and `realWidth` when you expect it to not animate anymore?

Comment: Now i've got 2 pages on slider. So `realWidth` is equal `(pages*820 - 820)`. So if `offset == 820 && realWidth == 820`, then right arrow must be blocked. When `offset = 0`, and i click right arrow, then `offset == 820` and slider is on second page and `offset = realWidth == 820` and right arrow must be blocked. One thing is very strange. When i click right arrow, animation isn't smooth, but when i click on left arrow animation is smooth.

Comment: i put `alert('a')` when `offset == realWidth` and `alert('b')` when animation is animate, and.. when `offset == realWidth` function return `false` and show `alert('a')`, but `alert('b')` isn't showed. So why animation is reseted and why next click on arrow move only few of previous animation width (only about 150px - one photo)? This is very strange for me... is here some crash?